Google Maps - Address Validation in Blazor/C#
I almost have it... but now I am getting a "404 - not found" error return. What am I missing??
(using the guide at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/validateAddress )
The Class created for posting the address (using a full address line" is:
 public class PostAddressData
 {
     public string regionCode {  get; set; }
     public string locality {  get; set; }
     public string addressLines { get; set; }
 }

The address string looks like: "78 Prince Edward ST, Saint John, NB, Canada"
string PostURI = $"https://addressvalidation.googleapis.com/v1:validateAddress?key={apiKey}";
 var postBody = new { Title = "Blazor POST Request Example" };
 Models.PostAddressData myAddress = new Models.PostAddressData();
 myAddress.regionCode = "CA";
 myAddress.addressLines = AddressLine;

 // POST the Json request for the address...
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(PostURI);
 var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myAddress);
 var theContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 var response = httpClient.PostAsync("address", theContent).Result;


I am trying to POST JSON data to the Google map API in C#.
Not sure if I have the correct code for formatting the header/body or not.
... and No the Geocoding library does not work for me in .NET 8.
Thanks in advance for any help!!

What error are you getting?
